# Running a Win32 executable on Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 image

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2

Has anyone tried to run a Win32 executable on Amazon's Windows 2008 Server image? I had tried but Amazon's Windows 2008 server image says the executable is not Win32.

I then tried the same executable on a local Windows XP and Windows 7 machine, and it could install fine.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Thanks!

Comment: Today I run many executables on Amazon's Windows 2008 Server images. No such problems? Maybe your executables corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error occurs at the opening of files, click Start / Run, then enter and confirm the following command:

> regsvr32 / i SHELL32.DLL

For other causes please check this article:

[.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1591-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application)